# Force an entire MySQL database to be in memory

Tags: mysql, database, linux, unit-testing

For the purposes of running a large number of tests that interact with the database, I want to do two things:

1. I would like to copy the schema of a database without copying its data. I can do this with a script that grabs the CREATE TABLE statements from each table in the database.
2. Upon creating this database, I would like to force it to be 100% in memory.

I'm stuck on how to do part 2 - Is there an easier way to do this other than specifying each table's engine? Somehow that seems like a poor way of doing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the database in `/dev/shm` (ubuntu|debian) and it will be in RAM. It can grow up to 0.5 of available memory.

Comment: This sounds good, but is there a similar solution for CentOS?

Comment: Check if you have it: $ mount | grep shm. Otherwise, you can create a filesystem on one of /dev/ram* and mount it somewhere.

Comment: Centos 5.0+ always has /dev/shm mounted. However, you can mount a tmpfs anywhere you like. tmpfs has been available for some time.

Comment: guys, dont know if its OK, just tried :  mv /usr/local/mysql/data/blah /dev/shm.... ln -s /dev/shm/blah -> data/blah.... restarted mysql... its flying

Answer (score 2):

As *dtmilano* said, you can put it on a tmpfs mounted filesystem. It doesn't have to be /dev/shm, but that is one place where tmpfs is usually mounted.

You can create a new one anywhere, though:

```
mount none -t tmpfs /path/to/dir
```

If it fills all your available RAM, it will use swap as a backup.

Put it in /etc/fstab to re-mount on boot. Just remember, it's a ram disk, so it starts out empty every time you reboot. See: http://www.howtoforge.com/storing-files-directories-in-memory-with-tmpfs

Alternately, as suggested by *yuxhuang* you can create a table of type `MEMORY`. It also empties on restart, though the table definition remains. The `MEMORY` table type has a few restrictions, though. It uses fixed-size rows, for example, so `text` and `blob`  columns are not allowed, and `varchar` isn't variable length. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SET storage_engine=MEMORY;
```

This is going to set the default storage engine for the current session.

Comment: There is a limit how large a MEMORY table can be. it is doubtful (but possible) that all the tables in a db will be able to be MEMORY tables

Comment: Memory tables still have their metadata stored on disc, and they don't behave the same as the other engines.

Comment: Further expanding @MarkR comment: `MyISAM` and `Innodb` are already very different and can lead to different behavior, leading to bugs that only happen to one engine. Thus, I recommend NOT changing your database engine to `MEMORY`, as it will very likely introduce engine-specific bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, in your database creation script you can create the tables adding the MEMORY parameter like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` varchar(23) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```